# Writing a separate package vs copy pasting small amount of reused code

Tags: dependencies, dependency-management

I have two npm packages that build on top of our core software platform. Their core functionality is mostly different, except for how they serialize data. This is and will predictably stay identical for as long as these systems operate. The code for serializing said data is very short (~200ish LOC), so the dilemma I'm faced with is how and if to best share it between the two code bases. The two approaches I've considered are

a) Making a separate npm package for the serialization code and importing that into both packages.

- Pro: If something in the underlying serialization changes, I only need to remember to change it in one place
- Pro: I can potentially reuse this in future projects
- Con: Making and maintaining a whole package for ~200 LOC feels like dependency bloat and an anti-pattern

b) Copy-pasting the code in both packages.

- Pro: No extra overhead of a separate package and extra dependency
- Con: If something changes, I need to remember to change it in both (or more in the future) places

Would love to hear someone else's two cents on this and if there is potentially and option c) I'm forgetting regarding this. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Obligatory warning about premature abstraction https://sandimetz.com/blog/2016/1/20/the-wrong-abstraction

Comment: I think the horror stories of `leftPad` and `isArray` swung the pendulum too far the other way. Packages are the unit of code reuse and sharing. You have a need to reuse and share code. Use packages.

Comment: You say "*on top of our core software platform*". Does that imply your core software platform already is distributed as a package?

Comment: Thanks for the additional comments - yes, the core platform is accessed via a package. The two packages I described here build on top of this in addition to sharing some serialization logic. (This serialization logic isn't a general thing for the core platform though, so putting that in the "core" package isn't really an option)

Comment: Relevant: http://yosefk.com/blog/redundancy-vs-dependencies-which-is-worse.html

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Isolating the serialization code in its own package is little overhead but significant benefits.

You already pointed out the reuse possibility the package, but in fact it offers more:

- **Separation of concerns**: the package encourages to have a better separation of concerns, i.e. when you change something you need to know/decide if it is to be part of the package or should belong to the context
- **Versionning**: it's easier to make the serialization evolve without breaking the running code. Imagine you add a new output format: not only will you do it in one place, but you can start the work, while still having no change on your main base.
- **Dependency management**: the dependency is visible instead of remaining hidden in the code base and known only by you. This makes the dependency more manageable (including in relation with versioning,  if you have for example to maintain several versions of your main base)
- **Testing**: having serialization in an independent package facilitates also to have a separate testing suite, checking also for extreme cases that would be difficult to verify if it is lixed with your main base.

Copy-pasting is in general a quick step forward, with benefits in the short term. Packaging may require some more thoughts, but provides long term benefits that will ease your future life significantly.

Comment: And ~200 LOC is not a good criteria. If you can give me what I need I don't care if it's 1 LOC.

Comment: Your points are correct, but the answer completely ignores the question for NPM packaging vs "Other options", And in fact, not everything needs to be an NPM package in the .Net world to achieve **all** of the bullet points you mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

Are those two NPM packages seen as independent products, with own versioning, individual repos, individual builds and releases? Or are they sharing a common repo, a common build process and are maintained by the same team?

For the latter, you might save the hassle of creating an additional, separate NPM package, and just reference the common source code or project or assembly (for now, you can still decide to make a separate NPM package later). There are different options for .Net projects which allow this, which are all a little bit more lightweight than creating a new NPM package.

For the former, having a 3rd NPM package is technically the best option. That is especially important when the serialization needs to stay identical for not breaking the system.

However, when there are no technical constraints dictating that the serialization must use similar code or data formats, and when you have two different teams for both packages which need to work independently from each other, copy-pasting 200 lines of code can sometimes be the better alternative. That may be the case when it is more important for an organization to allow their teams to release and maintain their products individually, without having to wait for another team when it comes to new requirements and bugfixes.

Comment: Why are people using npm with .net? Don't you guys have NuGet?

Comment: @slebetman: I was assuming by NPM, the OP meant "Nuget Package Manager"

Comment: NPM could also mean Node Package Manager.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the likelihood and the consequences of the need to change the code you are considering to package.

There can be two reasons for modification.

- it turns out you want different behavior for client A after all compared to the needs of client B.
- it turns out you did something wrong that impacts both client A and B in the same way.

In the first case you would be happy with the copy-paste solution. You started out by thinking you needed the same functionality for both but that turned out to be false. Hacking a switch into a package in order to support different clients is likely not going to be pretty or satisfying. You would rather just update the code used by client A.

In the second case you would be fine with the package solution. The copy-paste solution could still be not so bad but you would have to remember where the instances of the code are and update them all. As time passes, the code is more complicated and other people work on the product, this is more likely to be problematic.

Comment: +1. But let me add that it can also be an option to make a single package which allows a certain amount of customizing, so it can support slightly different needs of A and B. This is often hard to get right and more effort than it looks at a first glance, but netherless something which can be worth considering.